# AS3: drag by mouse or move by key

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, move

I've got 6 objects with drag'n'drop and hitTest function. It's obvious that when i drag one object to their hitTest area it's correct.

But my question is that i want to control these 6 object by mouse and keyboard keys. if i dont want to drag them, then i can move them by key arrows.

Second question is that when these two methods will be done if i want to move an object by key then i grab first free object which is not "hitTested"

Can I do these things in AS3? Pretty weird solutions in these project but i need to know if is possible.

Here's my code for drag and drop functions

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    var xPos:int;
    var yPos:int;
    var errors:int;
    var wins:int;

    public function Main():void
    {
        addListeners(objectone,objecttwo,objectthree,objectfour,objectfive);
        errors = 1;
        wins = 1;
    }

    private function getPosition(target:Object):void
    {
        xPos = target.x;
        yPos = target.y;
    }

    private function dragObject(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        info.text = "";
        getPosition(e.target);

        e.target.startDrag(true);
    }

    private function stopDragObject(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (e.target.hitTestObject(getChildByName(e.target.name + "Target")))
        {
            e.target.x = getChildByName(e.target.name + "Target").x;
            e.target.y = getChildByName(e.target.name + "Target").y;
            info.text = "Bingo!";
            wins++;
        }
        else
        {
            e.target.x = xPos;
            e.target.y = yPos;
            bledy.text = "Wrong: " + errors++;

        }
        if(errors == 4) {
            errors = 1;
            gotoAndPlay(2);
        }

        if(wins == 9) {
            wins = 1;
            gotoAndStop(3);
        }
        e.target.stopDrag();
    }

    private function addListeners(... objects):void
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
        {
            objects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragObject);
            objects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragObject);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Please give me some code tips!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For sure it is possible... and for sure there are several options to achieve that.

For the keyboard interaction I suggest you check FocusManager class so you can learn how to cycle trough selected objects using tab, and get the focused object.
Then listen for stage keyboard events to move with arrows the object.

Regarding dragging to move check the DragManager class related samples if using Flex, or look up google for tutorials in flash.

Comment: hmmm i'm using pure flash. i dont know anything about flex. Any code tips?

Comment: ok. you have to register for mouseDown event on the objects you want to move and then listen for stage.mouseMove and stage.mouseUu. On mouse up do the dragging/moving. On mouse up finish the dragging and remove listener to stage.mousemove and stage.mouseUp.